# Why is grid lying to me?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, grid

Sorry for the bad title, but WPF clearly is lying to me so I didn't know how else to word it. I've reproduced a very simple sample to demonstrate my problem:

XAML:

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" >
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Button Height="50" Grid.Row="0" ></Button>
        <Button Height="100" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="2"> </Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

This is what you get:

[image]

XAML Designer shows that the height of row 1 and 2 are 50 but they clearly aren't equal, so second row cannot have height of 50. I suspect this has something to do with the fact that I'm setting the second button's row span property to two but I don't understand why this messes up the row heights that I set by pixel.

How do I force it so that row 1 and 2's heights are fixed to 50?

Edit: I think I need to elaborate on my question. I maybe gravely misunderstanding how grids work, so please bear with me and let me know if I am.

First of all, what I am having a hard time understanding is

[image]

Why are the **heights** of the row 1 and 2 displayed as 50? They clearly aren't equal so Row 2 cannot have the height of 50. Is this a bug in design view or an expected behavior?

Because when I made my row definitions shown above, the below picture is what I expected (Note that the below picture is photoshopped to demonstrate my point):

[image]

Where the row 1,2 heights are **fixed to 50** and the remaining portion of the button is what the third row's height is set to.

Comment: The second button spans two rows with height 50 and 1*, which is exactly what the diagram shows.  What exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 3):

First of all - Your control may go out from the row or column size in Grid. So This is the expected behavior (Nobody is lying or cheating on you).

Instead of Using Height use MaxHeight property, Try this out:

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
            <RowDefinition MaxHeight="50"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button Height="50" Grid.Row="0" ></Button>
        <Button Height="100" Grid.Row="1"></Button>
</Grid>
```

Edit:

xaml design view is quite messy because it show you lot of things in a very small area. Hundreds of lines and if you have a large UI component then sometimes you cant even see some controls on view.

So Instead of analyzing xaml design viewer, if you use following two things then it will be easy for you to understand the UI of grid -

1. Set `ShowGridLines` property off `Grid` to true. This will show you the dotted border lines .
   2. Use [WPFInspecter](http://wpfinspector.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Well that certainly does solve my problem, but I'm still bewildered by this behavior. Please see my update to the question if you have the chance.

Comment: I have added some more lines to my answer. try this